# Render Google Maps from Google Maps API response

Tags: google-maps, laravel-5, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a route between point A to point B. I have been following the link below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Following link is an example of how to get the route between Montreal and Toronto. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=API_KEY

I get a JSON Response when I run this URL. I have checked a lot, but not able to figure how to render the details from this response into a map. Can someone please help by pointing me in the right direction ?

I have already checked this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

I am using alexpechkarev/google-maps package, and Laravel for building this solution. I have run the directions service from the package, which returns the JSON object which is similar to the one given by the link in the google maps api guide.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: draw route between two locations using js https://stackoverflow.com/a/52590827/4882013

Comment: Thanks @Shiv Kumar Baghel, for your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general recipe:

You need to extract the coordinates of the route from the JSON response.
These are in the response at 2 levels of detail.

1. The explicit coordinates of the major intersections along the route. You can read these in plain English and you can extract them as associative array members.
2. In addition to above, there is a coded string containing lots more `(lat, lon)` pairs of the points between the intersections. You have to decode these and there is an algorithm available. (I did a PHP version a few weeks ago and link is below). BTW the reason for this second array is this: Imagine a long winding country road with no intersections... this array will follow the road curves, giving `(lat,lon)` pairs not found in 1.

3). Build an array of coordinates (from 1 and including 2 if you need finer detail).

4) Then use code like below (stolen from below link and adjusted a bit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple:) that shows you how to draw the lines on a map.

```
<script>

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var routeCoordinates = [    // put your array here
          {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
          {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
          {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
        ];
        var routePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: routesCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',    // adjust line colour
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,        // adjust line opacity  
          strokeWeight: 2            // adjust line thickness
        });

        routePath.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
```

The example at the google link shows you how to do the tiny bit a HTML involved etc.

Now for the good bit to decode the polyline points:

[Get itinerary latitudes & longitude from google maps with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148962/get-itinerary-latitudes-longitude-from-google-maps-with-php/52157501#52157501)

In above the function `decodePolylinePoints($pointsString)` returns an array of `(lat,lons)` that you can use for drawing the route.

You need to study the `JSON` to understand the code, and while it looks messy its perfectly logical. Put the `JSON` in an editor like VSCode and it will be displayed properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks so much for the details. I am working on this. I will post my update shortly. Thanks again ! @bcperth

Comment: Your solution actually helped me in resolving my problem. I am accepting this as the solution. Saved me so much time and effort. Thanks !